# fade in/out hover by jQuery

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to add a simple fade in/out effect to the buttons by jQuery but I'm a bit stuck with fading out. I use this code:

```
$('#header #menu li a').hover(function () {
  $(this).fadeOut(0).addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);
},
function () {
  $(this).fadeOut(0).removeClass('hover').fadeIn(0);
});
```

It adds a hover class which defines a css background and fade the hover image in. But when I move a cursor out of the button, it simply disappears as normally, no fading out.

Can you help me with this please?

Thanks a lot for all replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two functions are opposites of each other, so should work... (**code updated**)

```
$('#header #menu li a').hover(function () {
  $(this).fadeOut(0).addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);
},
function () {
  $(this).fadeOut(300)
         .queue(function(){ $(this).removeClass('hover').fadeIn(0).dequeue() });
});
```

That's pretty ugly... See it in action on http://jsfiddle.net/zS6ex/.

However, you still have a problem: you're fading the **whole link** in or out, not only the image. As far as I know, you cannot set background image opacity separately (setting full opacity is already a pain if you do it manually...)

Comment: Unfortunately it does still the same problem :(.

Comment: still not convinced with the whole fadeOut(0) and fadeIn(0) why noy use show() and hide()? and whats wrong with just using the callback of fadeOut()?

Comment: I have bad experiences with mixing `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` and `show`/`hide`. The callback method should work, but seemingly doesn't... I haven't looked into that. This code **will** eat time and space, but too little to notice anywhere. I think programming was more interesting when you had to be careful your program fit in that three kilobytes of memory... but I wasn't around then.

Answer (score 3):

Like answered many times here on SO, you need to use the `callbacks` from jQuery `fx methods` to do anything **after** an animation has completed.

```
$('#menu li a').hover(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);
    });
}, function(){
});
```

Anyways, calling `.fadeOut(0)` would fade out that element with no animation at all, just like instant. First parameter is the duration.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, however the hover image stays on even if I move cursor away, it's weird.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just hide it while adding the  class since fadeOut(0) doesnt have an animation

```
$('#header #menu li a').hover(function () {
  $(this).hide().addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);
},
function () {
  $(this).hide().removeClass('hover').show();
  //  as there is no fading time the line above will be equal to
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

when you need something done after an animation has completed you should use callback `$(...).fadeIn(400,function(){ alert('this is the callback'); }`, if you dont use the callback the code is runned while the animation is going.

and i dont know if its usefull but there is a pseudo class `:hover` in css, see [here](http://w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_hover.asp)

> The :hover pseudo-class is supported
>   in all major browsers.

so with this you can do various things like:

```
#header #menu li a:hover { ...set style of 'a' when over 'a' }
#header #menu li:hover a { ...set style of 'a' when over 'li' }
```

just play with it a little and you can do a lot with just css

Comment: CSS can't do animation in the versions most browsers implement now, though Safari can do some crazy things with proprietary function-like code (blargh)...

Comment: thats true, the fading itself needs to be done in javascript but maybe the complete hover-class could be replaced