# Jquery Background / Text Color Fade

Tags: jquery, text, background, fade

I have a Jquery script below that simply fades in the background color on hover. While the background is fading as desired, the text is fading in and out as well which I don't want. Ideally, I'd like for only the background color to fade in and not the text.

Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks :)

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Set the anchor link opacity to 0 and begin hover function
    $("#menu-sample-menu li a").hover(function () {

        //Fade to an opacity of 1 at a speed of 200ms
        $(this).fadeOut(0).addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);

        //On mouse-off
    }, function () {

        //Fade to an opacity of 0 at a speed of 100ms
        $(this).fadeOut(300)
            .queue(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover').fadeIn(0).dequeue()
        });

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<nav id="access">
    <ul id="menu-sample-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-198"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/health-care-professional/">Health Care Professional</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-197" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-197"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/web-designer/">Web Designer</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-199" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-199"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/construction-worker/">Construction Worker</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Style

```
#access {
    padding:0 20px;
    background:#111;
    box-shadow:0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#access ul {
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:600;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#access li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#access ul li:first-child {
    padding-left:0;
}

#access a {
    display:block;
    padding:15px 24px;
    color:#f0f0f0;
    text-decoration:none;

}

#menu-sample-menu li {
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #777;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
}

#menu-sample-menu li a.hover {
    background: orange;
}


#access li.current_page_item > a,
#access li.current-menu-item > a {
    background: orange;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#access a span {
    color:#999;
    font-size:11px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1.62em;
    text-transform:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the [jQuery color animation plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color), and animate the `background-color` property.

Comment: Hey Joseph, thx for the response. I'll definitely give it a try. Before I do, to keep the scripts to a minimum, is there a way to achieve the effect I'm looking for without an additional plugin?

Comment: @user2325396 - You can add another element that is absolutely position to cover the whole parent element, then set its `z-index` to -1 so that it is positioned behind the content. You can fade *that* in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Thx for the info. If I were to use the color-animation plugin, could you provide some assistance on what the Jquery code would look like?

Comment: @user2325396 - Just use [jQuery's `animate` function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate the `background` color.